# Robolectric issue with appcompat-v7:22.2.0

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing, android-appcompat

After updating to appcompat-v7:22.2.0 some of my robolectric tests seem to fail.

Support libraries that i am using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Robolectric libraries

```
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3')
testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0-rc3')
```

Note: All my activites extend AppCompatActivity. Also using NavigationView from the new google design library.

Stack trace:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file ./../app/src/main/../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/res/layout-v11/abc_screen_content_include.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:814)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:321)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
at .HomeActivity_.setContentView(HomeActivity_.java:49)
at .HomeActivity_.onCreate(HomeActivity_.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:305)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
at .HomeActivityTest.setUp(HomeActivityTest.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:52)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:638)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:245)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:185)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:149)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:87)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 1):

If you followed this guide   http://nenick-android.blogspot.de/2015/02/android-studio-110-beta-4-and.html  you have a test-project.properties whith the intermediates

```
android.library.reference.1=../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3
```

Change the version of appcompat.

If you didn't use the guide read it, it can help a lot, or read the latest guide http://nenick-android.blogspot.de/2015/03/android-studio-110-and-robolectric-30.html

Comment: Tthe example code is more up to date https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

Comment: why do we need to add .properties file?